# Cannot set default and only culture in ASP.Net Core app

Tags: localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I'm working on Polish operating system:

In my `Statup.cs`class I have following code

```
        // Configure the localization options
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-GB")
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(
            new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
                FallBackToParentCultures = true,
                FallBackToParentUICultures = true,
                RequestCultureProviders = null
            });
```

The full options are for reference only to be sure that nothing is set behind. In my `_Layout.cshtml` I have following code:

```
<div>Current Culture: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName</div>
<div>Current UI Culture: @CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName</div>
```

The only supported and available culture should be `en-GB`, however on web site it is always showing:

```
Current Culture: Polski (Polska)
Current UI Culture: Polski (Polska)
```

I've tried to add `Microsoft.AspNet.Localization` package, but it makes no difference. Based on code in localization middleware, all should work as expected. I'm running latest version of ASP.NET Core 1.0.0.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem but without success. On a German system the view displayed the British culture just fine. Do you have a large application where other code segements may set the current culture directly ?

Comment: @rboe I've just made additional test.And there is one important thing. `UseRequestLocalization` have to be before `UseMvc`, otherwise it is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one important thing, not mentioned in documentation. `UseRequestLocalization` has to be placed before `UseMvc`, mine was below.

Comment: I have exactly the same situation, UseRequestLocalization has to be placed before UseMvc but it doesn't work. How can I solve it another way?

Comment: @YuriyN. what cultures do you have? Did you setu default culture or supported cultures?

Comment: I have uk and en cultures and set uk as default culture.

Comment: yuriy how did you solve this? i am facing the same issue