# Asp.net core 1.1 localization, doesn't change culture

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I followed the Microsoft tutorial about localization in Asp.Net Core and i have one issue, Culture doesn't change except if i change the default culture in Startup.cs file.

```
// Startup.cs - ConfigureServices Method
services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();



// Startup.cs - Configure Method
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{            
    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
    new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
    ...
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),            
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
    RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
});


// HomeController
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

and i want to change the language with an Anchor Link like:

`<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-culture="fr-FR" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path">FR</a>`

When i click the link the cookie successfully is getting set, the page reload but the localized text remains the same. When i change the DefaultRequestCulture in Startup.cs file the culture appear fine (which means my Resx files are properly named etc)

So how can i achieve to change the language based on the link that got clicked?

**EDIT**
I am still looking for a solution if anyone can help

**EDIT 2**
I made a new solution and the problem still occurred in VS 2017, i upload my VS Project on Github if anyone can take a better look and explain me what i am doing wrong https://github.com/adonis07/Localization

**EDIT 3** 
I was able to solve the problem by adding that nuget package in my solution  **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies** . Now the culture works properly.

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38499465/5417285

Answer (score -1):

Are you configuring the thread to change to a specific culture somewhere in your code? Something like this, wherever you read the language cookie:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
```

Comment: No and the tutorial doesn't mention something like that, i thought the culture provider would handle that by checking if any of the 3 options (Url, Cookie, Header) is set on each request.

Comment: Is this the default approach in an ASP.NET Core 1.1 website? I haven't done anything so far, i am waiting for a recommended way of changing the language